# Spark Streamin improving data pipeline but maintiaining continuous delivery

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-streaming

I am developing a data pipeline that will consume data from Kafka, process it via spark streaming and ingest it into Cassandra.

The data pipeline I will go into production will definitely evolve after several months. But how to move from old to new data pipeline, but to maintain continuous delivery and avoid any data loss?

Thank you

Comment: Asking for external resources is off-topic in SO. I'd remove that part if I were you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exact solution will depend on the specific requirements of your application. In general, Kafka will serve you as buffer. Messages going into Kafka are preserved following the topic expiration time.

In Spark streaming, you need to track the consumed offsets either automatically through snapshots, or manually (we do the later as that provides more recovery options).

Then you can stop, deploy a new version and restart your pipeline from where you previously left. In this model, messages are processed with at-least-once semantics and zero data loss.

Comment: maasg, could you please share information how do you store manualy offsets?

Comment: @Natalia: pls avoid piggy-backing questions on comments. That's a valid question that could be valuable to other people. Better to ask it separately.

Comment: @maasg: thank you for your answer. 

My spark job is using updateStateByKey transformation. Will that transformation be affected after I stop the old and switch to new spark job?

Will new spark job know what was the previous state?

Comment: @SrdjanNikitovic you will need to preserve snapshots and recover from them. See: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#checkpointing